# Filter out Duplicates that follow each other in Sequence with BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking for a way to filter out row sequences with the same column value while keeping the first element of the sequence.

Given the following table:

| id | location | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1001 |
| 2 | B | 1002 |
| 3 | A | 1003 |
| 4 | A **<---** | 1004 |
| 5 | A **<---** | 1005 |
| 6 | B | 1006 |

I want to produce the following output:

| id | location | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1001 |
| 2 | B | 1002 |
| 3 | A | 1003 |
| 6 | B | 1006 |

The goal is to remove row 4 and 5 because they both follow another location `A`. Only the 1st occurrence of the sequence should remain. I'm working with BigQuery SQL.

Comment: Is `timestamp` unique?

Comment: @ATOMP yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(location) over (order by timestamp) as prev_location
      from t
     ) t
where prev_location is null or prev_location <> location;
```